# scope of the connection object Con in jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

*Syntax  Error *

I am facing the problem with my JDBC.
In this line:

```
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:recordtbl","scott","tiger");
```

here at con error appear that i rename this variable.

This is my code:

```
package md5IntegrityCheck;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MD5IntegrityCheck
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
  {


      Statement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;
      Connection con=null;
      PreparedStatement pst=null;
      try
        {
          Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:recordtbl","scott","tiger");
                    }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {ee.printStackTrace( );}

          System.out.println("Step 1");
          System.out.println(con.isClosed());

          System.out.println("Enter the filename");
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          String filename=scanner.nextLine();
          String chksumno="somevalue2";


          // get the file name here and store it in filename variable;
          MD5 md5 = new MD5(filename);
          System.out.println("test");
          chksumno = md5.getHashValue();

          System.out.println("Step 2");
          try{
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:recordtbl","scott","tiger");

                pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into recordtbl values(?,?)");

          //System.out.println(pst.isClosed());
          System.out.println("Step3");
          pst.setString(1,filename);
          System.out.println("Step 4");
          pst.setString(2,chksumno);
          System.out.println("Step 5");
          pst.execute();

          System.out.println("Statement was EXECUTED!");
          con.close( );
          } 


          catch(Exception ee)
            {ee.printStackTrace( );}


    if (args.length <= 0)
    {
      Md5Gui gui = new Md5Gui();
      gui.runGui();
    }
    else
    {
      DoWork runningProgram = new DoWork();
      runningProgram.run(args);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please post the exact error message  you're getting

Answer (score 2):

You've already declared a local variable called `con` in the scope where you try to declare it for the second time. That's not allowed in Java. Just change it so that the second time it's an assignment instead of a declaration:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:recordtbl", "scott", "tiger");
```

(There are various other things I'd change about your code, including closing connections etc in `finally` blocks, but this should solve your immediate problem.)

Comment: hey JON my code is compiling to Step one ..rest of all is not compiled ...plz correct it

Comment: @user762357: I'm afraid I haven't got time to go through every little thing that might be wrong. Have you paid close attention to the compiler messages and tried to work out for yourself what's going wrong? Aside from anything else, you haven't posted the MD5, Md5Gui and DoWork classes, so I *can't* correct everything.

Comment: @user762357 - that's not the way SO operates.  We will answer your questions, but you have to do the work.  Start by READING the compiler error messages.